# ExtJs Tree Panel Not Reload from JSON Store

Tags: json, extjs, tree, store, reload

I am new in Extjs, using ExtJs 4.1.0, I made a tree panel in which the nodes are made from a JSON store. that is fine, but user trying to add/delete new record(or node) explicitly on button click, this shown from json response text the data is added or deleted, but it doesn't refresh the tree panel, kindly help me here. I have tried many methods like tree.getStore.Load() or treepanel.root.reload(); etc. nothing works and gives error as null.

```
    function MakeTreePanel(_store) {
    LeftPlanObjectenPanel = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
        store: _store,
        id: 'mytree',
        autoShow: true,
        //height: 500,
        rootVisible: false,
        clearOnLoad: true,
        border: false,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
//        listeners: {
//            itemclick: function (view, record, item, index, e) {
//                fnClickLeaf(record.raw.id);
//                //alert(record.raw.id);
//            }
//        }
    });
}
```

My store is like:

```
PlanObjectenStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    root: {
        expanded: true
    }
});

Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'DS_PlanObject.asmx/GetPlanObjectsByMindplanInJSON',
    timeout: ExtTimeoutVar,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' },
    jsonData: { DecisionType: DecisionType, DecisionNumber: DecisionNumber, DecisionTypeNumber: DecisionTypeNo, MindPlanID: MindPlanID },
    success: function (result, request) {
        //alert("Response: " + result.responseText);
        PlanObjectJsonCollectionData = Ext.decode(result.responseText);
        if (LeftPlanObjectenPanel == null) {
            PlanObjectenStore = eval('{' + PlanObjectJsonCollectionData.d[0].naam + '}');
            //PlanObjectenStore = eval('{Ext.create(\'Ext.data.TreeStore\', { root: { expanded: true, children: [{ text: "ABCD1234", expanded: true, id: "root", children: [{ text: "plangebied", expanded: true, id: "plangebied" }, { text: "ehs", expanded: true, id: "23" }, { text: "ehs text", expanded: true, id: "24" }, { text: "ehs water", expanded: true, id: "25" }, { text: "lkjlkj", expanded: true, id: "17" }, { text: "new praveen", expanded: true, id: "19" }, { text: "nitin kumar soni", expanded: true, id: "22" }, { text: "nitin soni", expanded: true, id: "20" }, { text: "pks", expanded: true, id: "12" }, { text: "test another", expanded: true, id: "18" }, { text: "test praveen", expanded: true, id: "8" }, { text: "Test1", expanded: true, id: "1" }, { text: "Test2", expanded: true, id: "2" }, { text: "Test3", expanded: true, id: "3" }, { text: "Test4", expanded: true, id: "4" }, { text: "Test5", expanded: true, id: "5" }, { text: "Test6", expanded: true, id: "6" }, { text: "testkees", expanded: true, id: "7" }, { text: "vcvc", expanded: true, id: "15" }, { text: "yes sharma ji", expanded: true, id: "11"}]}]} });}');
            MakeTreePanel(PlanObjectenStore);
        }
    },
    failure: function (result, request) {
        alert('error:LoadTree method' + result.responseText);
        var jsonData = Ext.decode(result.responseText);
        myMask.hide();
    }
});

On Saving record in table: I use to call like this:
LeftPlanObjectenPanel.root.reload();
```

Please let me know how can i re-load my tree panel. 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually, we can use:

```
treeStore.getRootNode().appendChild(...);
```

**Example**:

```
var decodedData = Ext.JSON.decode(data);
treeStore.getRootNode().appendChild(decodedData);
```

Comment: the Tree store got updated, but I am not sure how to refresh the Tree with this new store, What I am doing here is calling MakeTreePanel again with new store, but it disturbs the current tree and append new tree below existing one, how to clean up first tree, or is there something better way to reload existing tree with new store.

Comment: Try to refresh: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.view.View-method-refresh ( treeGridView.refresh() )

EDIT: 
But maybe it's better to do ajax request on the  store's proxy config, like this: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store

,the "treeStore.load()" will redraw the treeGrid component.